# Intermittent System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException on web server accessing network drive

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hangfire

We have a web server running hangfire that intermittently polls a shared network drive with a path example of:

```
\\SXXXXX\XXXXX$\XXX\
```

which intermittently throws a System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException however the directory is created by the same piece of code.

It seems to run fine 8/10 times and on the 2 times it throws the exception it actually deletes the folder if its empty which is code that runs after the point of the exception?

Here's an example code block:

```
 var downloadDirectory = "*OMITTED*
        Directory.CreateDirectory(downloadDirectory);
        TestDirectoryCreatedOnNetwork(downloadDirectory);


var dir = new DirectoryInfo(downloadDirectory);

        if (dir.GetFiles().Count() == 0)
        {
            Directory.Delete(downloadDirectory);
            return false;
        }
```

Googling brought us to the idea that: Directory.CreateDirectory() would potentially suffer from latency so we added the following:

```
private static void TestDirectoryCreatedOnNetwork(string directory)
    {
        int waitCount = 10;
        do
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(downloadDirectory))
            {
                break;
            }

            Thread.Sleep(10000); // sleep 100ms
            waitCount--;
            if (waitCount <= 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to create directory");
            }
        } while (true);
    }
```

We know that the code works because of the fact that it runs 8/10 times so we're not really sure where to go from here.

Thanks!

Comment: Smells like the network is intermittent. You need to catch that exception and wait to try again. Or fix your network, it stinks.

Comment: Maybe you have concurrent issue? One user delete the directory and another come at the same time? And I know that a web server and a network drive do not work well: I suggest that you put your files directy on a drive of the server, or like @Will said: put the data on a more stable drive like a SAN or a NAS (I always mix those 2)

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over the network. However, we set up a file system watcher on the folder directory in question and we did see the folders being created and deleted so the folder definitely exists at the time the exception is being thrown. We can however look at moving them to a local drive as suggested and see if there's any difference. There's no concurrency here as its all ran in background jobs that execute on timed intervals.

Comment: Without knowing what you're doing it's a bit hard to know. Is this just a different machine with a shared folder? Maybe upgrading to a SAN would be a better solution. Or drop the file on the web server's disk and use a different process to transfer them that runs in the background, possibly elevated or under a network account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments this was caused by poor network conditions, we've since moved the folder creation onto the actual web servers local drives and everything is now working